# Why get -1 when downvoting an answer?

Tags: discussion

I have recently earned +500 reputation points, and so now I am able to give reviews on three categories, which are:

- Triage
- First Post
- Late answer

Now as a member of Stack Overflow, it is my responsibility to check the posts and give honest review too , and so in some cases I have to give a downvote the answers too which cause -1 reputation to me. Why should I give a downvote to an answer if it is affecting my reputation (which are already less :P ). Please guide me to understand this rule of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling `String.reverseTheActualMeaning()` on the Joker's *If you are good at something, don't do it for free* line, you end up with - *If something is being done for free, it might not be good / right*. Everything has a *price*

The `-1` *rep strategy* is used to prevent people from recklessly down voting questions / answers. Though SO is smart enough to take care of *serial voting / down voting*, `-1` rep ensures that you actually *read* the question / answer before taking this action on individual questions / answers.

Comment: I got your point. But then I can ignore such post and move on , should I ?because being honest at the cost of -1 rep is not good for me as I have few reps.

Comment: @varsha - Yes you could move on without down voting. Actually, I only down vote questions answers which are very very bad. For me it is not about losing 1 rep. It is about *not discouraging the OP*. If the OP is a *help vampire* and if he is clearly asking for code without *showing even minimal effort*, then I strongly suggest down voting the question. If the answer is downright wrong, down vote it. For any other reason, you could give the OP the benefit of doubt.

Comment: ahaaa , so what I'm doing is not wrong if I ignore to downvote and yes it is discouraging the OP too.

Comment: @varsha - According to me you are not wrong. But opinions vary from person to person :)

Comment: yes but i think I'll do this way till I get at least half reps of yours :D

Comment: @varsha - Sure. All the best.. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 9):

To make sure that people are giving some thought to their downvotes, it costs 1 rep to cast a downvote.  That's all.

Free resources are almost always abused to exhaustion.  It's the same principle that causes rampant abuse of email; if email cost just 1 penny per recipient, spam worldwide would disappear overnight.